# Identifying Instrumental Variables to use in tsls function in sem R package

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, 2sls

I want to reproduce the Example from [Introduction to Econometrics by G. S. Maddala](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0023745452) in `R` using `tsls` function from `sem` package.  I'm confused how to identify the instrumental variables for the equations. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
## ---- fm42 ----
fm42 <-
  tsls(
      formula = Q~R+RD+X
    , instruments = ~R+RD+RS #Not Sure
    , data    = Data2SLS
    )

summary(fm42)
summary(fm42)$coeff
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simultaneous equations system, there are two kinds of variables: endogenous and exogenous.  "Endo" means inside.  "Exo" means outside.  "genous" means generated---these are derived from Greek root words.  Thus, the two kinds of variables are endogenous (generated inside the system) and exogenous (generated outside the system).

So, if we are looking at a system of equations describing a demand and supply system, and we want to know which variables are endogenous, then we need to ask ourselves "which variables are determined inside the demand and supply system?"  If we are only looking at one market (and, in your example, we are), then the answer is price and quantity of the product being sold in the market.  The usual demand and supply picture looks like this:[image]
Those dashed lines are the demand and supply system determining, endogenously, the price and quantity of the good, whatever it is.

The endogenous variables in a demand and supply system are never instruments.  Only the exogenous variables in a demand and supply system are candidates to be instruments.  Normally, we use all of the exogenous variables as instruments.  There are definitely exceptions to this, however, especially when we are studying the interaction among several markets at the same time.

How does this apply to your example?  Well, the market you are studying is the market for loans.  Quantity is quantity of loans, $Q$.  Price is price of loans, or, interest rate, $R$.  So, those are the endogenous variables (and, hence, NOT candidate instruments).  The exogenous variables are $RD$, $X$, $RS$, and $y$.  I assume that Maddala used all four of these as instruments in this case.

On my reading, your mistake is that you used $R$ as an instrument where you should not have and failed to use $X$ and $y$ as instruments where you should have.  So the instruments line should read:

```
 `, instruments=~RD+X+RS+y`.
```